# AWS infrastructure for AngularJS and Rails API production environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have developed a website with AngularJS running on an Nginx web server that sends request to a Rails API running on a Unicorn server and a MYSQL database.
   For testing purposes the application (both front-end and back-end) are currently running in an EC2 micro instance. The database is running in a RDS micro instance.
   The performance is not bad, but for production environment should be a little bit more faster.

I don´t know what exactly show I change, or what is a suitable infrastructure configuration.

Probably, I will test it, but I think maybe an EC2 small instance and a RDS small instance are more than enough. However, this configuration is not as cheap as expected. An EC2 small instance (in Ireland) is 0.047$/hour, this is more or less 33,84$/month. In the other hand a RDS small instance is 0,06$/hour, this is 43,60$/month. This is a total of  77,04$/month. Probably this is a good price for all this infrastructure, but it´s still expensive for our budget.

So, we are thinking if there is a more cost efficent combination. I. e.

1. I guess it´s possible to install a database shared with the application on the EC2 instance. This would save the RDS instance, right? Maybe, you could get a bigger (i.e medium) EC2 instance, and use it for both.

Or should a use an EC2 and RDS small instances? How would it be to keep the RDS instance as micro?

Comment: Honestly the only way to know for sure is to create a load performance test and check for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't comment on which size is better, but if you plan on running a website on AWS, presumably you will be running it 24x7x365. If that is the case, you should buy a reserved instance, not an on-demand instance and save a boatload of money.

For example, your small ec2 instance (that you priced at $0.047/hour) will amount to $1218.24 over a three year period (not including RDS).

If you bought a 3 year reserved instance it would cost you $578 instead. ($337 upfront then $0.009/hour x 24 x 31 x 36 months) = $578.

Personally, I would go for a medium or large instance on a 1 or 3 year 'contract' and run MySQL on the same box until performance started to suffer and then offload the MySQL to RDS down the road.

Comment: There's a proviso here: the reserved instance covers a particular size instance in a particular zone. If you decide to up/downsize the server within the 1 or 3 year period the reservation will no longer apply to your instance so you will be paying the on-demand price unless you buy a reserved instance that corresponds to the new size. You need to factor that in if you are likely to be resizing often in the initial period as you could end up paying more rather than less.

Comment: @E.J Brennan I agree with your answer. My only concern is if I run mySQL in my EC2 instance (instead of RDS), I guess I will lose some features provided by AWS, mainly database backups. I guess I can do this backups by myself with some scripts, right? Do you see any problem with this? According to ianjs: thanks for the advise. I think maybe the best will be to setup the infrastructure on demand and make some tests for some time. Once, sure it´s meets the requirements but a reserved instances.

Comment: true, you would give up some of the work that AWS would do for you, but yes, you can automated those and backup the files to S3 on a regular basis with some scripts instead. And @ianjs is also correct, so if you don't see the need for the server for three years, perhaps locking in only a 1 year would do instead; I almost always have other uses for servers if I need to resize the original so I usually don't worry about that - and, btw, you can also sell your unused reserved instances on the aws open market (I've bought several there from other folks wanting out of the remainder of their term).

Comment: @E.J Brennan this is great. I´m checking the prices (in Amazon) you talked above ($337 upfront then $0.009/hour x 24 x 31 x 36 months) = $578, but I don´t see it. Could you please let me know which kind of instance did you choose? Did you estimated it for Ireland region? I don´t see any 0.009$ anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, that was us-east, looks like it cost $0.013 for the 'heavy'/'m1.small' instance in the EU, but the upfront is actually only $187 - so its even cheaper than I said; cost = $187+.013 x 24hours x 31days x 36months = $535 for three years.